# Invalid Syntax and Unsure Why

Tags: python, syntax

I have been looking at this python error for hours now and have no idea why line 13 ("approx") is coming up as an error. I tried changing the parentheses in many different ways and am sure there are no telling mistakes; what could be wrong with this code? Thank you!

```
def Trapezoidal(t0, tN, u0, h):
    tlist = [t0, t0+h]
    ulist = [u0]
    iterations = (tN-t0)/h
    for i in range(int(iterations)):
        est = 1
        j=0
        newtonU = [u0]
        while est > (10**-6):
            g = ulist[i] + h*((-e**(-t))*x) - x
            gPrime = h*((-e**(-t)) - 1
            approx = newtonU[j] - ((ulist[i] - h*(e**(-tlist[i+1])*newtonU[j]) - newtonU[j]) / (-h*(e**(-tlist[i+1])) - 1))
            newtonU.append(approx)
            j = j+1
            est = ulist[i] + h*((-e**(-tlist[i+1]))*(approx)) - approx
        ulist.append(newtonU[-1])
        myt = tlist[-1] + h
        tlist.append(myt)
    result = ulist[-1]
    print(result)
#u^(.1)(1):
Trapezoidal(0, 1, 1, 0.1)
#u^(.05)(1):
Trapezoidal(0, 1, 1, 0.05)
#u^(.025)(1):
Trapezoidal(0, 1, 1, 0.025)
```

Comment: Please specify which error exactly, you just said it came up "as error"

Comment: Previous line, mismatched parentheses. (Remember to check for that in the future, because it's usually the problem.)

Comment: count the number of each type of parenthesis on the preceding line

Comment: Use an IDE with linter ;)

Comment: Thanks to everyone! Thought it had to be the line 13 it marked!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for providing a complete code example. It made it easy to find the error :) You are missing a closing parenthesis in `gPrime = h*((-e**(-t)) - 1)`

```
def Trapezoidal(t0, tN, u0, h):
    tlist = [t0, t0+h]
    ulist = [u0]
    iterations = (tN-t0)/h
    for i in range(int(iterations)):
        est = 1
        j=0
        newtonU = [u0]
        while est > (10**-6):
            g = ulist[i] + h*((-e**(-t))*x) - x
            gPrime = h*((-e**(-t)) - 1)
            approx = newtonU[j] - ((ulist[i] - h*(e**(-tlist[i+1])*newtonU[j]) - newtonU[j]) / (-h*(e**(-tlist[i+1])) - 1))
            newtonU.append(approx)
            j = j+1
            est = ulist[i] + h*((-e**(-tlist[i+1]))*(approx)) - approx
        ulist.append(newtonU[-1])
        myt = tlist[-1] + h
        tlist.append(myt)
    result = ulist[-1]
    print(result)
#u^(.1)(1):
Trapezoidal(0, 1, 1, 0.1)
#u^(.05)(1):
Trapezoidal(0, 1, 1, 0.05)
#u^(.025)(1):
Trapezoidal(0, 1, 1, 0.025)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there any reason it was marking the following line as the error?

Comment: Because you were missing a closing parenthesis, the python interpreter moved onto the next line thinking it continued the statement, and that line was not a valid part of the statement (e.g., you cannot assign variables within a variable assignment). As some commenters have said, you should look at the previous line if you can't find the error on the indicated line.